# How to find the difference between same column values in different rows with condition in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a data set of chat room with user activities join and leave room. A user can join and leave room multiple times. I need to find out the time spent by each user on each room.

```
  room_id user_id event   time  
  1       1       join    2021-12-10 09:00:00 
  1       2       join    2021-12-10 09:10:00 
  1       3       join    2021-12-10 09:20:00 
  1       2       leave   2021-12-10 09:30:00 
  1       1       leave   2021-12-10 09:40:00 
  1       1       join    2021-12-10 09:50:00 
  1       3       leave   2021-12-10 10:00:00 
  1       1       leave   2021-12-10 10:10:00
```

What I need is:

```
  room_id user_id time_spend
  1       1       60
  1       2       20
  1       1       30
```

I am new to redshift. I tried using lag function but wasn't able to add condition like join and leave. Can someone help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start based on your sample data:

```
create table test (room_id int, user_id int, event varchar(16), event_time  timestamp);

insert into test values  
(1,      1,      'join', '2021-12-10 09:00:00'),
(1,      2,      'join', '2021-12-10 09:10:00'), 
(1,      3,      'join', '2021-12-10 09:20:00'), 
(1,      2,      'leave', '2021-12-10 09:30:00'), 
(1,      1,      'leave', '2021-12-10 09:40:00'), 
(1,      1,      'join', '2021-12-10 09:50:00'), 
(1,      3,      'leave', '2021-12-10 10:00:00'), 
(1,      1,      'leave', '2021-12-10 10:10:00')
;

select * from test order by user_id, event_time;

select room_id, user_id, sum(time_spent) as time_spent
from (
    select room_id, user_id, event_time, decode(event,'join',event_time) as join_time, 
                lead(decode(event,'leave',event_time)) ignore NULLS OVER (partition by room_id, user_id order by event_time) as leave_time,
                datediff(min, join_time, leave_time) as time_spent
    from test)
group by room_id, user_id
order by room_id, user_id;
```